# Extjs Tree Store auto sync with server

Tags: model, extjs4, extjs

how to use store to sync with server when using a Tree ?

I tried to use [TreeStore](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.TreeStore) but it does not have any appendChild oder addChild.
[NodeInterface](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.data.NodeInterface) has a appendChild method but it does not sync with the server trough the store or proxy...

Any ideas ?

Comment: do you mean that your TreeStore structure can be dynamically change during the app?

Comment: yes, I'm building a file browser. I built a server with nodejs with CRUD operation and the user should be able to add,remove, move, rename (...) nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TreeStore haven't methods like Store.add or Store.delete. Because it needs information of parent node. So, example for add child to root element:

```
var root = me.getCategoryTree().getRootNode();
root.appendChild( rec );

me.getCategoryTree().getStore().sync();
```